# Can we override the functions of C++ STL containers?

Tags: oop, stl, c++14

As an example, I want to use **Min Heap** by using **priority_queue** and instead of deleting the smallest element, I want to override the **pop()** function to delete a **particular element** from Min Heap every time.

Comment: Which particular element do you want to remove each time?

Answer (score 1):

No.

`std::priority_queue::pop` isn't a virtual function, so even if you did subclass it and write a new one, it wouldn't be called from a `std::priority_queue &` or a `std::priority_queue *`.

If you want a max-heap, you can change one of `std::priority_queue`'s default parameters from `std::less` to `std::greater`, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
using max_heap = std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T>>;
```